# How to compute app widget bitmap size?

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget

I have a working widget that uses layouts and RemoteViews and scales itself nicely to whatever  home screen area assigned to it. However, I need to display custom fonts and thus must re implement using an explicit bitmap and here is where the problems start, computing the bitmap size ended up to be a tough problem.

What is a good formula to compute the widget bitmap size in pixels as a function of these
values (and anything else that is available and is useful):

1. Number of home screen rows (R) and columns (C) allocated to the widget.  (I derive min/max value in the widget_info.xml from these values).
2. Display metrics (screen size, DPI, density (D), etc)
3. Current orientation (O)
4. Android version (V)

The goal is not just to find a safe size but also not wasting screen real estate.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `getWidth` and `getHeight` on the parent layout of your Widget.  After the widget has been drawn once these values will be populated and you'll know the exact size of the widget.

Comment: This is an app widget, how do I access the parent layout of the widget? Does RemoteViews supports it?

Comment: Do app widgets not use a layout.xml file?

Comment: They do but they are inflated into RemoteViews, not View. RemoteViews has a subset of the functionality of View.